# interp3 spline NaN

Tags: matlab, interpolation, nan

I am having a very weird thing happen with `interp3` in MATLAB as you can see from the following output:

> > interp3(s, vw, rs, vwj, -2.8, 1.5, 1.2)

ans =

-2.3730e-06

> > interp3(s, vw, rs, vwj, -2.8, 1.5, 1.2, 'spline')

ans =

NaN

`XI`,`YI`,`ZI` are all firmly within the grid and linear (default) interpolation seems to work, but when I try a spline I get `NaN`s for any input arguments.  Weirder, if I specify an `extrapval` of say 1, if I try a spline I get 1s for all arguments.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show complete numerical example? Because result depends on s, vw, rs, vwj variables.

Comment: Ahh, i think i've discovered why: in my matrix i make some vals -inf if they are implausable, but when the thing tries to calc spline curves with -inf vals, it messes up.  but linear interp only bases the argument on the two adjacent points, so 1 -inf value does not mess up the whole grid.

Comment: I can close this up.  Thanks for your help mc2...

Comment: @RyanLewis, if you think the solution you found might be interesting to future readers, you should enter it as an answer. If not, you might consider deleting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `'nearest'` or `'linear'` in the option mode.

Comment: this will fix matters but extrapolation is not possible with these items.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, i think i've discovered why: in my matrix i make some vals -inf if they are implausable, but when the thing tries to calc spline curves with -inf vals, it messes up. but linear interp only bases the argument on the two adjacent points, so 1 -inf value does not mess up the whole grid.